# Need assistance with React Native Navigator for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to get a simple Navigation flow working. Below is my code.
Pageone and Pagetwo are 2 target navigation points.
end result is just a blank white page, no error ..dont see the nav bar or anything on the screen.. would appreciate any assistance..

Thanks !

```
//Nav.js


var PageOne = require('./pageone'),
PageTwo = require('./pagetwo'),
React = require('react-native');

var {
  Navigator,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = { 
  LeftButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.leftButton }</Text>
    )
  },
  Title: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.title }</Text>
    )
  },
  RightButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.rightButton }</Text>
    )
  }
}

var Nav = React.createClass({

  renderScene: function( route, nav ) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'PageOne':
        return <PageOne navigator={ nav } title={ "PageOne" } />
      case 'PageTwo':
        return <PageTwo navigator={ nav } leftButton={ "Back" } title={     "PageTwo" } />
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ id: 'PageOne', title: 'PageOne' }}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={( route ) => {
          if ( route.sceneConfig ) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
          }
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
        }}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar 
            routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper }/>
        }/>
    );
  },
});

module.exports=Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PageOne or PageTwo container element has the style attr:

```
flex: 1
```

For example:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
...
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work..wonder if Navigation works on Android at all..